# Quadratic form in R

Tags: r, linear-algebra, quadratic

This is probably straightforward, elementary and whatever, but I can't manage to get it. I have 2 `Nx1`vectors `u` and `w`, which are composed by both negative and positive values. I am trying to compute `w'u u'w` , which should be a quadratic form. I should be able to write this like

```
t(w)%*%u%*%t(u)%*%w
```

However sometimes I get a negative value, depending on the values in the two vectors. This is not possible, since that thing is a quadratic form. I tried with

```
crossprod(w, u)%*%crossprod(u, w)
```

and

```
crossprod(w, u)*crossprod(u, w)
```

which gives positive and equal results. However, since I am dealing with `Nx1`vectors, I should also be able to write it as

```
`sum(w*u)^2`
```

which gives a positive value but different from the ones above.

So I guess I am doing something wrong somewhere. So, the question is: how can I express `w'u u'w` which is valid for both vectors and matrices ?

EDIT: here a [csv file](http://www.filedropper.com/data_4) with the original vectors to reproduce exactly the same issue

Comment: Would you please provide a reproducible example of your data. You can use `dput` or check this (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: I could. But it does not matter, since the quadratic form must be positive no matter which the data is. And I apply that procedure for different vectors and for some it works, for others it does not. Hence the point is not the data. However, I will provide an example shortly

Comment: it is all about something to try your code with instead of generating random numbers

Comment: I added the csv.file. You can find it here http://www.filedropper.com/data_4

Comment: I don't get negative results with your data. I obtain roughly the same value whatever procedure I follow. I guess the small differences are due to loss of precision.

Comment: t(w)%*%u%*%t(u)%*%w gives -2.031317e-29,  which is negative. This brings problem when I go for sqrt( .. )

However, given the number of 0s, I think it is just as you say, machine approximation problems

Comment: me as well, I got positive values at all times.

Comment: Thanks people. It must definetly be the machine approximation issue due to loss of precision

Comment: just for you to check, I got this number 5.843948e-18 not -2.031317e-29

Comment: I got the same. If you multiply every data * 1000 you get exactly the same results. Thanks